# crating a list from answers

Tags: python, python-2.7, caesar-cipher

I am new on python and currently reading Hands-on cryptography with python, while I was reading the caesar5.py script on the book a question came across my mind and I would appreciate anyone who can help me out with it.
the code says:

```
alpha =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

str_in = raw_input("Enter ciphertext: ")

for shift in range(26):

  n = len(str_in)
  str_out = ""

  for i in range(n):
    c = str_in[i]
    loc = alpha.find(c)
    newloc = (loc + shift)%26
    str_out += alpha[newloc]
    print shift, str_out
```

and it prints the results in 26 rows, and I was wondering how can I print the results in one list?
instead of printing it like

```
0 KHOOR
1 LIPPS
.
.
.
25 JGNNQ
```

It just prints out `[KHOOR, LIPPS,...,JGNNQ]`, something like this.

Comment: instead of print ... just add it to a list ... then print the list...

Comment: Just an fyi, python 2.7 has been deprecated since 01/01/2020. Learning from a book written in python 2.7 will teach you some out-of-date syntax and may cause you some confusion down the road.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially what your looking to do is create an array in python.
There are tutorials on this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp.

I'll try to write the code out quickly:

```py
array = []
array.append(str_out)
```

Then at the end of the for loop:

```py
print(array)
```